# Does the Datanitro clear_row function have a row limit?

Tags: excel, datanitro

I am invoking the clear_row() function in the datanitro shell as follows:

> > > > clear_row(CellRange('A4:A69'))

Doing so creates the following error:

> > > > dntypes.NitroExpection: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

However, the following call works correctly:

> > > > clear_row(CellRange('A4:A68'))

As does this call:

> > > > clear_row(CellRange('A40:A100'))

Is there a row limit in the clear_row method and, if so, can this limit be eliminated?